# Scrape PDF embedded in .php page

Tags: python, php, selenium, web-scraping

I've been scraping text embedded in pdf's from pages that directly show the pdf (page url ends with '.pdf') with no problem so far (Using Selenium in Python). But now I've run into a new batch that the pdf is embedded in a php page.
For example say the page is (not the actual page):

https://www.example.com/ADIR_871/civil/documentos/docu.php?valorEncTxtDmda=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvb2ZpY2luYWp1ZGljaWFsdmlydHVhbC5wanVkLmNsIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL29maWNpbmFqdWRpY2lhbHZpcnR1YWwucGp1ZC5jbCIsImlhdCI6MTYwMzQ3MzE2NSwiZXhwIjoxNjAzNDc2NzY1LCJkYXRhIjp7ImNycl9pZGRvY3VtZW50IjoiMTMyNzQ3NDQiLCJjb2RpX3RyaWJ1bmFsIjoiMjYzIiwiZW50aXBhcmNoaXZvIjoiMyJ9fQ.cB_GJ9sfSq_cvoS2-DvUBfJTesGhfcfl51gRGPvOpGg

Then if I inspect the page, the content part would be the following:

```
<div id="content"><embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" src="https://www.example.com/ADIR_871/civil/documentos/docu.php?valorEncTxtDmda=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvb2ZpY2luYWp1ZGljaWFsdmlydHVhbC5wanVkLmNsIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL29maWNpbmFqdWRpY2lhbHZpcnR1YWwucGp1ZC5jbCIsImlhdCI6MTYwMzQ3MzE2NSwiZXhwIjoxNjAzNDc2NzY1LCJkYXRhIjp7ImNycl9pZGRvY3VtZW50IjoiMTMyNzQ3NDQiLCJjb2RpX3RyaWJ1bmFsIjoiMjYzIiwiZW50aXBhcmNoaXZvIjoiMyJ9fQ.cB_GJ9sfSq_cvoS2-DvUBfJTesGhfcfl51gRGPvOpGg" stream-url="chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/0cae9446-1142-4eb3-af15-353847788604" headers="Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Connection: close
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=&quot;Document.pdf&quot;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/pdf
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2020 18:03:23 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: public
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
" background-color="0xFF525659" top-toolbar-height="56" javascript="allow" full-frame=""></div>
```

So I can't even get to the source PDF because the src is the same url that I'm looking at!

Also I don't know if this gives any info, but when i right click the page and put inspect, instead of opening the inspect side bar as usual, a pop up is open with the inspect toolbar, super weird. Also if I request the html, I get a different one that the one in the pop up. I get this if requesting the html with selenium:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin:0px; background-color: rgb(82, 86, 89);">
<embed name="FD96F78861CE08FA8F7A5D67836A1B70" style="position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" src="about:blank" type="application/pdf" internalid="FD96F78861CE08FA8F7A5D67836A1B70">
</body>
</html>
```

Is this common?

The PDF just has some embedded text. It feels weird that I can see it in my screen but I can't scrape it with Python. How could I get this text?
Thank you!

Comment: I cannot offer a full answer but there are two things to consider:

1. It's possible to embed a PDF without ever requesting one, by setting its base64 data eg assuming `pdfdoc` is an embed object, by `          document.getElementById("pdfdoc").src = "data:application/pdf;base64," + 'JVBERi0xLjUKJdDUx.....'`
If that's the case then you have the full PDF in the src attribute, in base64 format. Based on the details you provide though this doesn't seem to be the case, but just in case.

Comment: 2. If the page is actually requesting the PDF to the server (the most likely scenario), but for some reason the src attribute is not showing it, try https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/, and look for the request you need.

Comment: Thank you Diego! Unfortunatelly the page is requesting the PDF to the server, since there is no 'base64'. I also don't know how to use requests. I added mor info to the question I dont know if it helps! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simulating mouse click copy all and accessing the clipboard, no need to ever have the pdf.

```
    import mouse
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
    import pyperclip

    mouse.click('left')
    keyboard = Controller()
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press('a')
    keyboard.release('a')
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press(Key.ctrl)
    keyboard.press('c')
    keyboard.release('c')
    keyboard.release(Key.ctrl)
    text = pyperclip.paste()
```